# How to automate adding contacts to a Microsoft Teams group using C#

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I'd like to use the Microsoft Graph NuGet package to write code in C# (console app) which will add contacts to one of the contact groups I created in the Teams messaging UI.

I can't seem to figure out:

1. where this data is stored in Graph
2. how to modify the data
3. what permissions my client application will need to modify this data

Comment: Do you want to add members to a team using Graph? Please check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-post-members?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) for adding member to a team using Graph API. It lists all the permissions required and here is a [sample code](https://github.com/OfficeDev/msteams-sample-adminbot-csharp).

Comment: @Gousia-MSFT No - I'm not talking about adding members to a team. I want to add members to a user-created contact group. For instance, open up the Teams application (desktop), click on the "Chat" tab on the left, then the "Contacts" tab at the top (beside "Recent"). I want to add users to one of the contact groups that the user created there.

Comment: Currently only sending messages to Teams is supported. Sending messages to the contact groups is not supported. You could instead add those members to the team and send a message there.

Comment: @Gousia-MSFT I don't want to send messages to contact groups. I simply want to populate contact groups using  the API.

Comment: Ah! am sorry i meant currently only adding members to a team is supported. API to add members to a group is not currently supported. Thanks!

Comment: @GousiaBegum Is there anything new on the topic of Teams contact group management via API (adding members, creating contact groups)? Is there any technical documentation available on how those contact groups are implemented under the hood?

Comment: Note: I asked in a more general way over in Microsoft Q&A since I suspect that topic might get more traction there. -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/729032/what-are-microsoft-teams-contact-groups-built-on-h.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the comment from  @Gousia-MSFT, adding members to a contact group from the API is not supported at this time.